# Mobx não gera arquivo .g.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, recentemente meu projeto do nada simplesmente começou a não gerar o arquivo .g.dart quando eu importo alguma classe no model, até mesmo as classes que já estavam importadas se eu deixo ele da erro e não gera o arquivo.

De forma totalmente estranha, o único erro que é me retornado ao executar o app é esse:

```
lib/mobx/nomeModel.dart:5:6: Error: Can't use 'lib/mobx/nomeModel.g.dart' as a part, because it has no 'part of' declaration.
part 'nomeModel.g.dart';

lib/mobx/nomeModel.dart:7:41: Error: Type '_$nomeModel' not found.
class nomeModel= _nomeModel with _$nomeModel;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alguém já teve esse problema ou sabe como resolver?

Comment: Ta faltando tu declarar o `part of` da sua store, que é responsável por criar o arquiovo g.dart... Só com isso ai que nos mostrou não da pra te responder nada que seja útil. Aqui no [package](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx) tem um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

O nome do arquivo g.dart normalmente deixo com letra minúscula, pois ele será o nome do arquivo a ser gerado, diferenciar os nomes também é uma boa, por exemplo:

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
part 'nomemodel.g.dart';

class NomeModel = NomeModelStore with _$NomeModel;

abstract class NomeModelStore with Store {
 
}
```